# There is no error shown and when any of the buttons in the activity are pressed, the app forces close?

Tags: android, button, forceclose

Why are the buttons forcing the app to close, there are no errors that have been highlighted and as i am new to android development, i can't find the problem. Any help is appreciated thanks.

This is the xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="447dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Categories" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
        android:onClick="Author"
        android:text="@string/Author"
        android:textColor="#FA6900"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/religion"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
         android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
         android:onClick="Religion"
         android:text="@string/Religion"
         android:textColor="#FA6900"
         android:textSize="21sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/politician"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
         android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
         android:onClick="Politician"
         android:text="@string/Politician"
         android:textColor="#FA6900"
         android:textSize="21sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/happy"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
         android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
         android:onClick="Happiness"
         android:text="@string/happy"
         android:textColor="#FA6900"
         android:textSize="21sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/sport"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
         android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
         android:onClick="Sport"
         android:text="@string/Sport"
         android:textColor="#FA6900"
         android:textSize="21sp" />
</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Java

```
package com.android.motivateme3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Categories extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    public void Sport(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sport.class);
        Vibrator  vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(25);
        startActivity(intent);
}    
    public void Religion(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Religion.class); 
        Vibrator  vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(25);
        startActivity(intent);}

    public void Author(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Author.class); 
    Vibrator  vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(25);
    startActivity(intent);}

    public void Politician(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Politician.class);
        Vibrator  vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(25);
        startActivity(intent);}

    public void Happiness(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Happiness.class); 
        Vibrator  vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(25);
        startActivity(intent);}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.categories, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

LogCat

```
05-04 16:08:41.014: D/memalloc(28579): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x60519000 size:18690048 offset:14921728 fd:73
05-04 16:08:41.054: D/memalloc(28579): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x61a6c000 size:35233792 offset:31465472 fd:79
05-04 16:08:41.064: D/OpenGLRenderer(28579): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-04 16:08:41.074: D/memalloc(28579): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5c63f000 size:31465472 offset:27697152
05-04 16:08:41.074: D/memalloc(28579): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5ebfb000 size:10366976 offset:6598656
05-04 16:08:41.084: D/memalloc(28579): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5f5de000 size:14921728 offset:11153408
05-04 16:08:41.824: D/memalloc(28579): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5c63f000 size:14921728 offset:11153408 fd:64
05-04 16:08:42.344: D/AndroidRuntime(28579): Shutting down VM
05-04 16:08:42.344: W/dalvikvm(28579): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ac4210)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.motivateme3/com.android.motivateme3.Author}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at com.android.motivateme3.Author.setupActionBar(Author.java:39)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at com.android.motivateme3.Author.onCreate(Author.java:28)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
05-04 16:08:42.354: E/AndroidRuntime(28579):    ... 11 more
05-04 16:08:49.964: I/Process(28579): Sending signal. PID: 28579 SIG: 9
05-04 16:11:35.094: D/memalloc(28746): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5f932000 size:10366976 offset:6598656 fd:70
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-feature android:name="@string/hello_world" />
    <uses-feature android:name="@string/Politician" />
    <uses-feature android:name="@string/Sport" />
    <uses-feature android:name="@string/Religion" />
    <uses-feature android:name="@string/Author" />
    <uses-feature android:name="@string/happy" />
    <uses-feature android:name="@string/responseno" />
    <uses-feature android:name="@string/responseyes" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.Sport"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sport"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.motivateme3.Categories" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.Religion"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_religion"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.motivateme3.Categories" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.Author"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_author"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.motivateme3.Categories" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.Politician"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_politician"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.motivateme3.Categories" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.Sports"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sports"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.motivateme3.Categories" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.Happiness"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_happiness"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.motivateme3.Categories" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.Feedback"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_feedback"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.Categories"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categories"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.motivateme3.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.motivateme3.Favourites"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favourites" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Author activity java
    package com.android.motivateme3;

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;

public class Author extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_author);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

             ImageButton NextQuote = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);
                final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                NextQuote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Vibrator  vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(25);
                         Random numGen = new Random();
                        int rNumber = numGen.nextInt(10);

                    if (rNumber  == 0)
                    {   
                        display.setText(R.string.Author1);
                    }
                    else if (rNumber  == 1)
                    {   
                        display.setText(R.string.Author2);
                    }
                    else if (rNumber  == 2)
                    { 
                        display.setText(R.string.Author3);
                    }
                    else if (rNumber  == 3)
                    {
                        display.setText(R.string.Author4);
                    }
                    else if (rNumber  == 4)
                    {
                        display.setText(R.string.Author5);
                    }
                    else if (rNumber  == 5)
                    {
                        display.setText(R.string.Author6);
                    }
                    else if (rNumber  == 6)
                    {
                        display.setText(R.string.Author7);
                    }
                    else if (rNumber  == 7)
                    {
                        display.setText(R.string.Author8);
                    }
                    else if (rNumber  == 8)
                    {
                        display.setText(R.string.Author9);
                    }
                    else if (rNumber  == 9)
                    {
                        display.setText(R.string.Author10);
                    }       }
                });
                        }

                    ImageButton Sharing = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.share);
                    Sharing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v){
                            Vibrator  vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vibrator.vibrate(25);
                        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        String quote = text.getText().toString();{
                        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.setType("plain/text");
                        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is a great quote (from the Motivate Me! app)");
                        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, quote);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via:"));}};});}








    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.author, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

XML author

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Author" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Next"
        android:onClick="NextQuote"
        android:src="@drawable/navigationnextitem" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/next"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share"
        android:onClick="Sharing"
        android:src="@drawable/socialshare" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:text="@string/Getstarted"
        android:textColor="#FF6900"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the theme used in your acivity ? Can you show us your `Manifest`file ?

Comment: A suggestion use activity context in place of getApplicationContext()

Comment: I have posted the xml manifest

Comment: can you please post the following class here:com.android.motivateme3/com.android.motivateme3.Author      I want to see the author oncreate method in particular

Comment: I have posted the author activity java

Comment: and now show this xml file for me activity_author

Comment: ImageButton NextQuote = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next); that will be the issue isn't it - what is this `next` widget?

Comment: hmm can we see this   R.menu.author  actually no need ...

Comment: have you tried simple Button instead of ImageButton? - `Button NextQuote = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);` and also modify the xml removing the src attribute and the name to <Button>

Comment: I hope for the sake of sanity that your code (specifically your indention and curly braces) are not actually formatted in the manner that you've posted them here.

Comment: what are line 39 and 28 on author.java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

can you go to project menu in eclipse and then do clean ..after you clean run the project and see if that resolves the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Your xml files, You set realtive parameters like this

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
```

should be

```
android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView1"
```

without '+' sign.

'+' sign means that android should generate new id for this value. If You don't use + it means the id already exists or is generated somewhere else.

To be more precise. If You use an id for first time in xml file You need + if You used it already don't use +

So if You need first element to be align to 2nd element You will use + sign within first element align attribute and later for 2nd element You don't use + when assigning id value.
If You align 2nd element to 1st You set id of first element with + and 2nd element align parameter without +.
It may sound a bit confusing but I hope You understand.

Your author xml will look like thi

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Author" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Next"
    android:onClick="NextQuote"
    android:src="@drawable/navigationnextitem" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/next"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonpress"
    android:contentDescription="@string/share"
    android:onClick="Sharing"
    android:src="@drawable/socialshare" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:text="@string/Getstarted"
    android:textColor="#FF6900"
    android:textSize="23sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have defined "@+id/next" in another layout xml file as a TextView